# How to update boolean value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm trying to update the `occupied` field of `runn` to `true` during the creation of a `stay`.

```
def create
    if params[:id].present?
      @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
      @stay = @patient.stays.build(stay_params)
      @stay.is_current = true
      Runn.find_by_id(@stay.runn_id).update_attribute(:occupied, true)
    else
      @stay = Stays.new(stay_params)
    end
    if @stay.save
      redirect_to @patient
    end
  end
```

This is the create method in my `stays_controller.rb`

```
class Stay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  has_one :runn
  has_many :feeding_events
  has_many :ud_events
  has_many :misc_stay_events

  after_create :update
  private
    def update
        self.check_in_dt = Time.new
        self.is_current = true
    end
end
```

This is `stay.rb`

```
class Runn < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :ward
  belongs_to :stay

end
```

This is runn.rb

When I use the console to display all, they all show that `occupied` is false, which makes sense because that's how I set it in seeds. However, I'm wondering how to update `occupied`? When I do:

```
[1] pry(main)> Runn.find_by_id(1)
  Runn Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "runns".* FROM "runns" WHERE "runns"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Runn:0x007f478460d6c8
 id: 1,
 ident: "Run 0.0",
 size: "Medium,",
 amenities: nil,
 created_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:50:01 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:50:01 UTC +00:00,
 ward_id: 1,
 occupied: false>
[2] pry(main)> Runn.find_by_id(1).occupied = true
  Runn Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "runns".* FROM "runns" WHERE "runns"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> true
[3] pry(main)> Runn.find_by_id(1)
  Runn Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "runns".* FROM "runns" WHERE "runns"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Runn:0x007f478467a6b0
 id: 1,
 ident: "Run 0.0",
 size: "Medium,",
 amenities: nil,
 created_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:50:01 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:50:01 UTC +00:00,
 ward_id: 1,
 occupied: false>
[4] pry(main)>
```

The `occupied` has not been update. However, with `update_attribute`:

```
[4] pry(main)> Runn.find_by_id(1).update_attribute(:occupied, true)
  Runn Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "runns".* FROM "runns" WHERE "runns"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "runns" SET "occupied" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "runns"."id" = $3  [["occupied", "t"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-03 05:52:33.949456"], ["id", 1]]
   (11.0ms)  COMMIT
=> true
[5] pry(main)> Runn.find_by_id(1)
  Runn Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "runns".* FROM "runns" WHERE "runns"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Runn:0x007f479d0fd098
 id: 1,
 ident: "Run 0.0",
 size: "Medium,",
 amenities: nil,
 created_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:50:01 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:52:33 UTC +00:00,
 ward_id: 1,
 occupied: true>
[6] pry(main)> Runn.all
  Runn Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "runns".* FROM "runns"
=> [#<Runn:0x007f479d0aafa0
  id: 2,
  ident: "Run 0.1",
  size: "Small,",
  amenities: nil,
  created_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:50:01 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:50:01 UTC +00:00,
  ward_id: 1,
  occupied: false>,
 #<Runn:0x007f479d0aae60
  id: 3,
  ident: "Run 1.0",
  size: "Small,",
  amenities: nil,
  created_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:50:01 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:50:01 UTC +00:00,
  ward_id: 2,
  occupied: false>,
 #<Runn:0x007f479d0aad20
  id: 4,
  ident: "Run 1.1",
  size: "Medium,",
  amenities: nil,
```

It has been successfully updated, but it has been removed from Runn.all. Any advice?

EDIT:

```
[1] pry(main)> Runn.all
  Runn Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "runns".* FROM "runns"
=> [#<Runn:0x007f4784e9b3a8
  id: 1,
  ident: "Run 0.0",
  size: "Medium,",
  amenities: nil,
  created_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:59:02 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:59:02 UTC +00:00,
  ward_id: 1,
  occupied: false>,
 #<Runn:0x007f4784e98a40
  id: 2,
  ident: "Run 0.1",
  size: "Small,",
  amenities: nil,
  created_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:59:02 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 05:59:02 UTC +00:00,
  ward_id: 1,
  occupied: false>,
 #<Runn:0x007f4784e98900
  id: 3,
  ident: "Run 1.0",
  size: "Small,",
  amenities: nil,
```

original Runn.all.

Comment: You set `.update_attribute(:occupied, true)` for Runn having Id `1`. However in `Runn.all` there is no record of runn having id `1`.

Comment: i'll reset the db and post my original Runn.all. It existed originally

Comment: How are you getting `@stay.runn_id` in `Runn.find_by_id(@stay.runn_id).update_attribute(:occupied, true)` ?

Comment: After setting it to true you may need to save the object with object.save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this to update:

```
runn = Runn.find_by_id(1)
if !runn.nil?
  runn.occupied = true
  runn.save
end
```

Comment: this removes it as well from Runn.all, similar to `update_attribute`

Comment: It won't be removed. I guess there might be `scope :all` in `Runn` model which filtered it out. You can double check it with comparing `Runn.count` and `Runn.all.count`

Comment: `if !` in ruby is same, as `unless`. `find` works same, as `find_by_id`, you do not need the latter. Oneliner: `run.update!(occupied: true) if run.present?` (or, if you will, `unless run.nil?`)